# how to remove the comment line starts with // and not the url like http:// using preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to remove the comment lines from my code.

```
preg_replace('!//(.*)!', '', $test);
```

It works fine. But it removes the website url also and left the url like http:

So to avoid this I put the same like `preg_replace('![^:]//(.*)!', '', $test);`

It's work fine. But the problem is if my code has the line like below

```
$code = 'something';// comment here
```

It will replace the comment line with the semicolon. that is after replace my above code would be

```
$code = 'something'
```

So it generates error.

I just need to delete the single line comments and the url should remain same.

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
preg_replace('@(?<!http:)//.*@','',$test);
```

also read more about PCRE assertions http://cz.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php

Comment: Thank YOU. But it generates the warning message Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'h'

Comment: sorry - delimiter corrected - now it works, at least what I have tested

Comment: You also can write [http|https] instance of http to accept both protocoles : preg_replace('@(?<![http|https]:)//.*@','',$test);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse a PHP file, and manipulate the PHP code it contains, the best solution *(even if a bit difficult)* is to use the [**Tokenizer**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) : it exists to allow manipulation of PHP code.

Working with regular expressions for such a thing is a bad idea...

For instance, you thought about `http://` ; but what about strings that contain `//` ?

Like this one, for example :

```
$str = "this is // a test";
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur help. But actually I want to remove the comments from javascript file through php

Comment: Oh :-( ;; still, using regex is probably not such a good idea : there will always be a case you will not have thought about... depending on what exactly you want to achieve, maybe something like the YUI Compressor might help ? http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion pascal. This code works well preg_replace('@(?<!http:)//.*@','',$test);

Answer (score 0):

This can get complicated fast. There are more uses for `//` in strings. If you are parsing PHP code, I highly suggest you take a look at the [PHP tokenizer](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php). It's specifically designed to parse PHP code.

Question: Why are you trying to strip comments in the first place?

**Edit**: I see now you are trying to parse JavaScript, not PHP. So, why not use a javascript minifier instead? It will strip comments, whitespace and do a lot more to make your file as small as possible.

Comment: Yes. Its true. But I need temporary solution for time being. Thats y searched this. Got solution. Thank YOU